# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_random_seed'

Tags: caffe

I got the error which is `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_random_seed'` when I tried to run `py-faster-rcnn` with my own `dataset.`
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what branch of `caffe` are you using? how did you clone it?

Comment: I just used --recursive to clone py-faster-rcnn.

Answer (score 3):

This is probability because you are using Tensorflow 2. So, instead you can simply use

```
import tensorflow as tf    
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in a different project, and it was because I had installed tensorflow 2 instead of 1. You can work around that by replacing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

with

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```